# getDerivedStateFromProps with setTimeout to change object state failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any clue why getDerivedStateFromProps doesn't setState to error.msg in below case? What I want is I can use alert component like so  and in MyError will show and hide it. I'm stuck at making the setTimeout to work.

```
export default class MyError extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      error: props.error
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(nextProps.error.msg !== prevState.error.msg) {
      console.log('compare state with props')
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('do something')
        return {
          error: {msg: ''}
        }
      }, nextProps.error.timeout)
    }

    return null
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.error.msg}</div>;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/myk9vklq2y

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is asynchronous, and the return value of its callback is discarded. Your getDerivedStateFromProps always returns null, so nothing will update (null indicates updating nothing).